# Can I force Cloudflare worker region? So that it works with a specific Microsoft Azure API?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, cloudflare-workers

I have a cloudflare worker setup that calls an external Microsoft Azure API. It works locally (wrangler dev) but not from ther published endpoint. I receive the following error from Microsoft:

"Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource."

After reading through the MS documentation, I found that I must call the API from the same region I created my subscription key from (US West 2). Since I live in US West area, I'm assuming that the local testing works since the request comes from there, but since I don't know where the published cloudflare worker is executing, MS is rejecting it.

So my question - can I force the external API to route through a certain region?

Do you think I would be better off spinning up an Azure Function? I'm really enjoying Cloudflare workers and am bummed with this error!

Thank you!

Comment: I think it's unlikely that this API actually requires the client to be located in a particular region. Internet routing can be unpredictable, which would make it very hard to satisfy such a constraint consistently, so it probably isn't designed that way. More likely what the error message means is that you are supposed to send the request to a hostname corresponding to the desired region. But since it works in local testing, I'm guessing you're already doing that, and the real problem may be that the "subscription key" is incorrect in your production deployment?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The docs say to "Select the testing console in the region where you created your resource:" https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-2/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499f21f

I've triple-checked the key but I'll have another look. Thanks again.

Comment: I ended up deploying the code to an Azure function in same region and it's working great but would still love to see if I can get a cloudflare worker ... working. :)